# Background color differences in sheet vs sub views

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Im having this weird issue where when a sheet is presented there is a color difference between the picker and the subview (forms). This might be a really dumb question, but I cant figure it out.

Any suggestions?

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Picker("", selection: $selection) {
            Text("Main Info").tag(Selection.main)
            Text("Contacts").tag(Selection.contacts)
            Text("Task").tag(Selection.tasks)
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .padding()
        switch selection {
        case .main:
            ModifyMainInformation(mainInformation: $account.mainInformation)
        case .contacts:
            ContactListView(contacts: $account.contacts)
        case .tasks:
            Text("Tasks Editor")
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .navigationTitle("Add Account")
}

enum Selection {
    case main
    case contacts
    case tasks
}
```

}

Subview Code:

```
var body: some View {
    
    Form{
        TextField("Account Name", text: $mainInformation.name)
        TextField("Address", text: $mainInformation.address)
        TextField("City", text: $mainInformation.city)
        }
}
```

}

Comment: The bottom is likely a safe area and the picker area needs a background set or some other modification to make it match, this is all expected, form has a very specific look.

Answer (score 0):

struct ViewA: View {

```
init(){
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .green <- here
}
var body: some View {
   .....
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately